# ./gitlab-deploy/.gitlab-deploy.staging.sh: line 8: “0”: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "“0”")

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I'm writing a script in bash and I get this error for deployment into my ec2:

And this is my code:

```
# !/bin/bash
#Get servers list
set -f
string=$QA_DEPLOY_SERVER
array=(${string//,/ })
#Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit
for i in “${!array[@]}”; do
  echo “Deploy project on server ${array[i]}”   
  ssh ubuntu@${array[i]} "cd /opt/bau && git pull origin master"
done
```

What is wrong with the script and how do I fix it? Many Thanks.

Comment: You say that the error is on line 16, but you don't tell us which line this is.

Comment: Perhaps you have spaces in variables, where you do an unquoted parameter expansion. Run your script with `-x` to check.

Comment: hi so the error is happening at the: "echo “Deploy project on server ${array[i]}" line, have updated my question.

Comment: The code has "smart quotes", are these in your actual code as well? Compare `“”` vs. `""`

Comment: yes, those are in my code. i have been following this article to: https://lucabecchetti.medium.com/autodeploy-from-gitlab-to-multiple-aws-ec2-instances-a43448727c5a

Comment: @BenjaminW. : Indeed it looks odd, but **this** error can not produce the error message encountered. I suspect line 8 is the `ssh` command; that's why I suggested the OP to trace his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you  @BenjaminW

I had to change "smart quotes" which were causing the issue in my script. Changing from `“”` to `""` fixed the issue.

Below is my updated script

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh ubuntu@${array[i]} "cd /opt/bau && git pull origin master"
done
```